# Generic Makefile with automatic make dependencies for multiple executables

Tags: c, makefile

Here is the more or less generic Makefile I came up with. What it does is that it checks all source files, **generate dependencies** and create the executable exec (named after the corresponding source file). Obviously, every files are in one folder.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=
LDLIBS=

BIN=exec

SRC=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJ=$(SRC:.c=.o)

all: makefile.dep $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)

makefile.dep: $(SRC)
    gcc -MM $^ > $@

include makefile.dep

.PHONY: all
```

What I'd like is to somehow extend this Makefile to handle multiple definitions of main. I guess what I have to do is to remove from $(OBJ) the object file of all source file containing a main function like so :

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=
LDLIBS=

BIN=exec
BIN2=toto

SRC=$(wildcard *.c)
JOBS=$(SRC:.c=.o)
JOBS:=$(filter-out $(BIN).o,$(OBJ))
JOBS:=$(filter-out $(BIN2).o,$(OBJ))

all: makefile.dep $(BIN) $(BIN2)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
$(BIN2): $(OBJ)

makefile.dep: $(SRC)
    gcc -MM $^ > $@

include makefile.dep

.PHONY: all
```

While it does seem to work, I wonder if there is a more elegant way that could achieve the same result without having to duplicate lines for each executable for example. Also, at the linking step of both executable, all object files are used, even the ones not needed (it may introduces bugs?).

Comment: If you do not want want to list source files explicitly (i.e. without wildcards), then *make* is probably not the right tool. Have a look at more recent build tools such as *cmake*.

Comment: Errr... cmake REQUIRES you to list source files explicitly; there's not even an _option_ for wildcards.  So your comment doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

In general using `wildcard` to find your source files is a bad idea.  You should keep a list of the files you want to build explicitly in your makefile.  It's much less error-prone and people don't add new source files so often that updating the makefile is a huge hassle.

You can use:

```
exec_SRC = exec.c foo.c bar.c
toto_SRC = toto.c biz.c baz.c

all: exec toto

exec: $(exec_SRC:.c=.o)
toto: $(toto_SRC:.c=.o)
```

There are LOTS of other ways to do it.  This is just one straightforward way.  If you have only a few of these you might as well keep it simple.  If you start to have lots of them maybe something more complex is warranted.