# Makefile: Adding a single *.h dependency for multiple executables

Tags: c, makefile, include

There are many "Makefile" examples for multiple executables. 
After a lot of trials and errors, I found this is following as the simplest one.

```
CC      = gcc
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
EXECS   = $(SOURCES:%.c=%)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EXECS)

clean:
    rm -f $(EXECS)
```

However, I could not find any simple example for including one "include.h" dependency for all those programs.  Please, could anybody show me?

JW.

PS:

- I have no idea about this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832230/generic-makefile-with-automatic-make-dependencies-for-multiple-executables).
- Thanks to @MadScientist, the answer is:

```
CC      = gcc
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
EXECS   = $(SOURCES:%.c=%)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EXECS)

$(EXECS): include.h

clean:
    rm -f $(EXECS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makefile is fine if you have a set of executables, each of which is built from exactly one source file.

In this situation you can just write:

```
$(EXECS): include.h
```

and you're done.